# Implementing count model in database

Tags: design, database, mysql

I've run into bit of an issue on implementing a `count` system in my project.

I have a system where users can like a `post`. Should I keep a count of it in the same table like

[image]

or should I remove the `like_count` column from the post table.

My concern if I have `like_count` column in the post table is -- frequent update of the value.

If I choose **not to add** a `like_count` column in the post table, I'd have to use `count()` frequently to display the details.
I've to design a data model for thousands of users.
So which model is the right way to implement?

P.S: Please ignore the data types of the columns. I just did a quick version of it to post it here.

Comment: You are doing caching, and, denormalizing you data model.. Perfectly valid but only when warrented, should not be your first choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First:**

- In the diagram `post_id` is the PK of `PostLikes` forcing any post to have only one like. PK should be `(post_id,user_id)`
- Table names should be singular, so `PostLikes` should be named `POST_LIKE`.

That said, **my recommendation is:**

A like counting feature is not a critical one (like, say the balance of a bank account) -- meaning, it is not critical to have the very exact like count of a post at any given second -- so in that case I suggest you to keep the `LIKE` table as well as the `like_count` column in `POST` and update it every N minutes. You don't even have to update every post's like count every N minutes. Every run of the batch process can update the count of a group of posts or the most recently liked ones.

Please note that with such a column you are knowingly de-normalizing for performance's sake, which is OK if well sustained.

Comment: Thank your for answer. As I had mentioned, I just made up a quick diagram for illustration purposes. In the actual table, the PK is as you had stated and the table names too. 

Would your recommendation be any different if I were to make all my reads(select statements) from a *SLAVE*  and only DDL in *Master*

Comment: Thank you for the edit. May I ask what would be the normalised way of doing it?

Comment: I guess you mean DML. In that case my recommendation would be the same.

Comment: @MageshKumaar The normalized version is not having a calculated column in any table and doing the count() every time you need it. That could be a performance issue if the table has no proper indexes or the table has billions of rows, since RDBMS don't scale well, performance-wise, into the billions of rows.

Comment: I've decided to go with the normalized version of this since table growth is not expected to be as large as that. Thank you for your help. Just one more thing, for a NON-RDBMS solution, which would you recommend ?

Comment: @MageshKumaar Maybe I exagerated, and maybe the performance hit would be felt at the hundred of thounsands (much less) and not the billions of rows. I have no experience in no-SQL database technologies but I guess my recommendation is similar to what you would do in a no-SQL database, where consistency has less priority than performance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't optimize ahead of time.

Essentially you are trading a "Count" for more frequents writes to your "Post" table and having to keep things in sync.  I would remove the "like_count" column for now and write System tests to profile your applications performance.

If it becomes a performance problem you can optimize at that point.

EDIT:  Didn't realize it was already a performance problem.

From a performance point of view there is just not enough information here to say which would perform better overall.

EDIT2:  changed my mind

From a design point of view it makes more sense keeping it on the "posts" table if you are unable to optimize it away.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got into this dilemma because of the scalability issue. I'd remove like_count column too from the posts table.

Comment: @MageshKumaar  Hmm would be curious what the query looks like, how many rows in each table there are, and what the runtime of the query is.  Also are you using any locks that would get in the way of database read operations?

Comment: This is still in the design phase so actual queries for reading the data does not exist (yet). I'd like to fix the DB design for the most part of it before proceeding with the actual code.

Comment: Didn't notice your edit before. I agree that there's not enough information since it's just a design problem. Would you still go with the removal of the `like_count` column from the `posts` table?

Comment: @MageshKumaar  Since you are de-normalizing things it probably makes more sense to keep it on the "posts" table.  Your "READ" operations will get the bulk of the benefit which is what is driving this anyway.